# use free texture packer for phaser3

Tags: javascript, textures, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm using phaser3 and free texture packer, is it possible to do that? if yes please tell me how?
I tried to use `addAtlasJSONHash` but it was logging that this function is undefined, so I tried `game.addAtlasJSONHash`, but the same error was happening

Comment: did my second answer help, or is something else unclear?

Comment: yes, thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your use case there a serveral ways, for the https://free-tex-packer.com/. Here is one fast/easy way, to get everything up and running.
*(**Just in case:** I assume you are using Phaser3)*

**In the App**

- Select Format: "Phaser3"
- Add images
- click export
- download the zip

**In Phaser**

- Unpack the *json* and *png* file from the *zip* into our game-app-folder
- in Scene preload: load the file(s), with `atlas`([docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.FileTypes.AtlasJSONFile.html))

  ```
    this.load.atlas('atlas', 'texture.png', 'texture.json');
  ```
- to add a sprite to the scene just use ([docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html)):

  ```
    // parameters are x,y, texture / atlas, frame-index
    this.add.sprite(10, 10, 'atlas', 0);
  ```

***Extra-Info:** On the official phaser webpage there are many examples, to most of the features. check out this basic one for `atlas` https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/textures/frames-from-single-atlas*

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ***old***, but did you checkout this tutorial?
https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/how-to-create-sprite-sheets-for-phaser3

It exmplains how this, is done with `multiatlas`.

Comment: I'm not using texture packer, I'm using http://free-tex-packer.com/

Comment: @5alidshammout You are right I posted a new answer with a short howto for the free app.